# customized names on x-axis on achart engine

Tags: android, achartengine

i am new to android app development.
i am using a-chart engine to dynamically generate a graph, my Question is can we place custom names on the x-axis, i,e can we place country names instead of values such as 10,20,30 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible, you have to set custom x axis labels:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, text);
```

To remove the default values call

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
renderer.setYLabels(0);
```

Make sure you are using ACE 1.0.0.